# Pizza box and lunch box in SMBIOS

Tags: standards, bios

The [SMBIOS spec](http://dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0134_2.7.1.pdf) lists Pizza Box (05h) and Lunch Box (10h) as the meaning for System Enclosure or Chassis Types. The other stuff makes sense but these do not. Are there really chassis types that corresponds to these types? If so, could someone please point out examples for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Pizza box form factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pizza_box_form_factor) or [lunchbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_form_factor#Lunch_Box) form factor is a style of case for computers or network switches.  Cases of this type tend to be wide and flat, normally one or two rack units (1U or 2U, 1¾ or 3½ inch, 4.4 or 8.9 cm) in height, thus resembling pizza delivery boxes.